# is there any way to add inline schema with xml using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

is there any way to add inline schema with xml using jaxb?I want to mean that I need to add the schema with the schema generated xml file.I give an examole as given below

```
<transaction>
  <xs:schema id="transaction" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="transaction" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="id">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="in" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="data">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="productData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <id>
    <in>computer</in>
    <sn>1234567</sn>
    <book>JAVA</book>
    <author>klen</author>
  </id>
  <data>
    <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
    <key>Err</key>
  </data>
</transaction>
```

I can only generate xml file look like

```
<transaction>
      <id>
        <in>abcd</in>
        <sn>1234567</sn>
        <book>computer</book>
        <author>klen</author>
      </id>
      <data>
        <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
        <key>Err</key>
      </data>
</transaction>
```

but I can not add inline xmlschema with is xml. my xml generated code looks like

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transaction.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT,true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(transaction, file);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(transaction, System.out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've missed something in the question, but what prevents you from writing following two lines?

```
Document trxDoc = .....; // this is what you have after marshalling
Document schemaDoc = .....; // this is your Schema document

Node schemaNode = trxDoc.importNode(schemaDoc.getDocumentElement(), true);
trxDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(schemaNode);
```

Here I assume that you have Schema document and marshal object to DOM Node.

Comment: can u explain briefly I can not understand because I am new in java please explain.

Comment: I added code where I marshal my document as per your code I think you create xml using DOM parser but want to try it using totally jaxb.is it possible?

Comment: @saba, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html , there is an example how to marshal to a DOM Node. As a result you will have DOM representation of your transaction (`trxDoc` in my text). Then you import root element from your schema document into newly created transaction document.

Comment: my xml is too large so I do not want to create node child manually by code I want to use jaxb by which I can generate xml file easily and after that I want to add schema with this document

Comment: @saba, jaxb is not intended for such sort of things, but if it were, then it'd do exactly the same. For large files SAX or StAX marshaling is recommmended.

Comment: Osw actually jaxb generate java classes from schema and this classes have get() set() method by which I can set value and generate the xml file.Now I want to add this schema with this xml file.Is there any way to add schema with using the this generated xml file?If we not add schema with my xml using jaxb can it possible to add schema object creating by dom,sax or stax and add this object with jaxb created object and then marshal it.

Comment: @saba, sure you can transform schema to String and have geteer/setter for it. And, aside from details, WHY do you need it that way? What are you going to do with that schema later? I have a feeling, that you've missed something on a higher level and there are better ways to achieve your goal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9547/discussion-between-saba-and-osw)